# Error decoding timecode using ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, timecode, metadata

I'm using `ffprobe` to get timecode from an `mxf` which has DF timecode but with a non DF frame rate. I'm getting the error `Drop frame is only allowed with 30000/1001 or 60000/1001 FPS`.

I'm running `ffprobe -i "IMX 10bit.mxf" -print_format json -show_streams -show_format` and getting the following:

```
ffprobe version 3.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
{
[mxf @ 0000000000da9740] Drop frame is only allowed with 30000/1001 or 60000/1001 FPS
Input #0, mxf, from 'IMX 10bit.mxf':
  Metadata:
    uid             : 2b3801ea-ec5e-4dc1-ab3a-dba9a2b30ce4
    generation_uid  : 2b3801ea-ec5e-4dc2-ab3a-dba9a2b30ce4
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    modification_date: 2009-11-04T10:39:42.000000Z
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D43130000005C91020063D700800210F3FFFE154618
  Duration: 00:00:19.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 62580 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv, top first), 720x608 [SAR 152:135 DAR 4:3], 50000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D43130000005D91020063D700800210F3FFFE154618
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 4 channels, s32 (24 bit), 4608 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D43130000005D91020063D700800210F3FFFE154618
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mpeg2video",
            "codec_long_name": "MPEG-2 video",
            "profile": "4:2:2",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/25",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 720,
            "height": 608,
            "coded_width": 0,
            "coded_height": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "152:135",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "4:3",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv422p",
            "level": 5,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "chroma_location": "topleft",
            "field_order": "tt",
            "refs": 1,
            "r_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "time_base": "1/25",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 488,
            "duration": "19.520000",
            "bit_rate": "50000000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D43130000005D91020063D700800210F3FFFE154618"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 4,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 936960,
            "duration": "19.520000",
            "bit_rate": "4608000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D43130000005D91020063D700800210F3FFFE154618"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "IMX 10bit.mxf",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mxf",
        "format_long_name": "MXF (Material eXchange Format)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "19.520000",
        "size": "152695808",
        "bit_rate": "62580249",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "uid": "2b3801ea-ec5e-4dc1-ab3a-dba9a2b30ce4",
            "generation_uid": "2b3801ea-ec5e-4dc2-ab3a-dba9a2b30ce4",
            "product_uid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "modification_date": "2009-11-04T10:39:42.000000Z",
            "material_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D43130000005C91020063D700800210F3FFFE154618"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer to your current problem. But consider filling out the SMPTE Time Label survey found [at the bottom of this page](https://www.smpte.org/lifewithoutsmpte/SMPTETimeCode) to share your experiences with time code.

Comment: can you run ffprobe -i {filename} -print_format json -show_streams 
and then post the result please?

Comment: Do it with `-show_format` as well.

Comment: Done. I've looked into the `ffmpeg` code base and it seems that timecode has its own frame rate specified...maybe this file was converted from an 29.97 to 25 without converting the timecode framerate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on here, but anyway you don't need DF timecode when you have NDF footage - this appears to be running at 25FPS so the timecode will run in real time anyway. DF is only going to be useful to you when you are running at a non-integer frame rate.